# What's the intuition behind the conjugate gradient method?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, intuition, numerical-optimization

I have been searching for an intuitive explanation of the [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) (as it relates to gradient descent) for at least two years without luck.

I even find articles like ["An Introduction to the Conjugate Gradient Method Without the Agonizing Pain"](http://www.ncts.ncku.edu.tw/phys/cmr/071123/cg.pdf) hard to understand.

Intuitively, what does this method do (e.g. **geometrically**) and why does it outperform gradient descent?

Comment: I've took the course, though not really remember things, here Michael explains the method and why it outperforms gradient descent. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZVK_PGE0_I. The thing was, the expanding manifold property - see starting around minute 40 in the first lecture, then continues in Lecture 11

Comment: That might be because you're looking at an abbreviated version of Shewchuk's "...Agonizing Pain" article. [The original](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf) is full of diagrams and gives a lot of geometrical intuition.

Answer (score 12):

Just giving an intuitive overview. [Michael Zubilevsky's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZVK_PGE0_I) lectures go through it in more technical detail.

Consider the quadratic objective $f(x) = x^T Q x + b^T x$. Geometrically, CG tries to "unwarp" some of the geometry induced by the quadratic form $Q$.

To build intuition, consider $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. If $Q = I$, then the contours of $f$ are circles. If $Q$ is diagonal, then the contours of $f$ are $x$-axis and $y$-axis aligned ellipses. If $Q$ has off-diagonal components as well, then there is "correlation" between the $x$ and $y$ directions, so the contours are ellipses whose principal axes are a combination of the $x$- and $y$-axis.

Now consider performing coordinate descent in the $Q=I$ or $Q$ diagonal case. We can reach the optimum in at most $2$ steps by viewing the problem as two $1$-dimensional minimization problems over each coordinate. We have this property because the $x$- and $y$-axis are orthogonal, and they "align" with the geometry of $Q$.

In the case where $Q$ contains off-diagonal components, CG finds orthogonal directions in $Q$'s geometry so that we can perform coordinate descent. We can use Gram-Schmidt to do the orthogonalization to find orthogonal directions, but if we start by orthogonalizing against the gradient, then we observe a lot of simplification in the update rule.

It outperforms gradient descent because by orthogonality of search directions, we ensure that we're never repeating a step along a direction we've searched in before. Thus we get rid of the "zig-zagging" of GD.

[EDIT: some additional notes [here](https://jacob-roth.github.io/files/conjugategradient.pdf)]

Comment: Is it correct to say that, since generally (negative of) normals of ellipse doesn't directly point to center, CG use the local information to redirect those (negative of) normals to center?

Comment: If it's true, then each CG step is equivalent to: 1) rescale the (locally) n-ellipse into n-circle, 2) perform steepest gradient.

Comment: I'll have to think a little and get back to you, but my first reaction is that what you're describing is like Newton's method

Comment: Sorry maybe I am wrong, but the ellipse thing kind of remind me of svd...

Comment: @somebody4: I'm only thinking in the convex quadratic function case for now, but the thing is that Newton can give you information to "rescale" the ellipse to a circle all at once, but CG does so in a step-wise fashion (search "expanding manifold property" for more on Krylov / spectral analysis)

Answer (score 3):

Check the full version of

[Shewchuk (1994) An Introdution to the Conjugate Gradient Method without Pain](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf)

This pdf is a 64 page document with 40+ figures (full of geometric insights). The version you got is just a 17 page version of the full document, without figures.

Answer (score -1):

Gradient descent with an optimal step results in orthogonal directions, that makes a sort of "Zig-zaging" when heading to the minimum, i.e., to have an optimal step $f(x_k+\alpha d_k)$ is minimized according to $\alpha$:
$d f(x_k+\alpha d_k)/d \alpha=0 \Rightarrow \nabla^T f(x_{k+1})\nabla f(x_k)=0 (i.e.: d^{T}_{k+1} d_k=0)$

To overcome this problem, conjugate gradients method makes the directions not orthogonal by puting:
$d^{T}_{k+1} Q d_k =0 $.
And finally the CG gives:
$x_{k+1}=x_k-\alpha \nabla f(x_k) + (\alpha_k \beta_{k-1}/\alpha_{k-1})(x_k-x_{k-1})$. Note this the same as gradient descent plus a term called Momentum term which works on accelerating the algorithm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).